# Minor ticks in matplotlib's colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to set minor ticks in the colorbar but simply can't make it work. There are 3 approaches which I've tried (see code below), but all of them didn't appear to be working. Is it actually possible to have minor ticks in the colorbar?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter

# fill grid
x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y = np.linspace(1,10,10)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.abs(np.cos(X**2 - Y**2) * X**2 * Y)

# plot
f, ax = subplots(1)
p = plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, norm=LogNorm(), vmin=1e-2, vmax=1e2)
cb = plt.colorbar(p, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal', aspect=10)

minor_ticks = np.arange(1,10,2)
#cb.set_ticks(minor_ticks, minor=True) # error: doesn't support keyword argument 'minor'
#cb.ax.xaxis.set_ticks(minor_ticks, minor=True) # plots an extremely small colorbar, with wrong ticks
#cb.ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(minor_ticks)) # nothing happens
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need `cb.ax.minorticks_on()`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

# fill grid
x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y = np.linspace(1,10,10)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.abs(np.cos(X**2 - Y**2) * X**2 * Y)

# plot
f, ax = plt.subplots()
p = plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, norm=LogNorm(), vmin=1e-2, vmax=1e2)
cb = plt.colorbar(p, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal', aspect=10)

cb.ax.minorticks_on()

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you want just the ticks that you specify, you still set them in the "normal" way, but be aware that the colorbar axes coordinate system ranges from 0-1 regardless of the range of your data.

For that reason, to set the specific values that you want, we need to call the normalize the tick locations using the same `norm` instance that the image is using.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

# fill grid
x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y = np.linspace(1,10,10)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.abs(np.cos(X**2 - Y**2) * X**2 * Y)

# plot
f, ax = plt.subplots()
p = plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, norm=LogNorm(), vmin=1e-2, vmax=1e2)
cb = plt.colorbar(p, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal', aspect=10)

# We need to nomalize the tick locations so that they're in the range from 0-1...
minorticks = p.norm(np.arange(1, 10, 2))
cb.ax.xaxis.set_ticks(minorticks, minor=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this; for whatever reason `set_minor_locator` and `set_minor_formatter` seem to be ignored when they are called on the axis object; only `ticks = <locator>.tick_values(*mappable.get_clim())`; `axis.set_ticks(mappable.norm(ticks), minor=True)` will correctly set the minor locator every time. Very strange. Hopefully the colorbar API gets cleaned up in future versions because right now it seems quite messy -- I've also had issues with using `set_major_locator` and `set_major_formatter` rather than passing the `locator=<locator>` and `format=<formatter>` kwargs.